# Кто может быть "владельцем" чата, признанного общим?

Tags: обсуждение, модерация, чат

Мне кажется, что назрел вопрос о принятии решения кто может быть *владельцем* общего/главного "чата", в котором общаются несколько участников сообщества, и какие ограничения накладываются на данного участника в этом случае.

Answer (score 7):

#### Предлагаю считать комнату общей тогда и только тогда, когда среди её владельцев есть только ромбовые модераторы.

И, соответственно, комнаты, в которых это не так, общими не признавать.

На мой взгляд, **общий** чат по определению **не должен иметь владельцев вообще**.

А отсутствие активных в комнате владельцев приводит к добавлению нового из числа "завсегдатаев" автоматически. Конечно, любую автоматику можно отменить, если очень хорошо попросить и предоставить очень весомые доводы, но в нашем случае в этом нет большой необходимости.

В связи с особенностями работы системы действия владельцев чат-комнат всегда доступны и ромбовым модераторам. Поэтому их присутствие в списке владельцев комнаты реально ни на чьи привилегии не влияет, а потому можно считать несущественным. Но их присутствие в списке владельцев и активность в комнате дадут системе понять, что новых владельцев избирать не надо.

Ромбовые модераторы либо являются сотрудниками Stack Overflow, либо честно избраны на выборах сообществом же. Первым сообщество доверять вынуждено, а вторых оно само выдвинуло. Всё честно.

---

Если говорить о конкретных кандидатурах, то здравой идеей выглядит назначение во владельцы общей комнаты менеджера соответствующего сообщества, при условии, что у него есть ромбовые привилегии. Менеджер сообщества, как правило, проявляет какую-никакую активность в чате сообщества; достаточную, чтобы система не назначала новых владельцев.

Или, для гарантии, можно зачислить весь ромбово-модераторский состав сообщества, чтобы снизить до минимума вероятность автовыбора нового владельца из числа активных участников.

Comment: у менеджера сообщества априори ромб в его сообществе :-)

Comment: @Grundy мало ли какое тут подсообщество образуют со своим самопровозглашённым менеджером :Р

Comment: Нам нужно тогда создать общую комнату (из существующей предпочтительнее).

Comment: А не ромбовые модераторы это кто?

Comment: @alexolut технически, владелец комнаты занимается в том числе её модерацией и может называться модератором. А может и нет. Возможные разночтения лучше исключать сразу, при обнаружении.

Comment: @alexolut любой пользователь с 10к репутации имеет доступ к так называемым инструментам модератора и потому может им называться.

Comment: @PavelMayorov я считаю, они должны называться инструментами модерации, а не модератора. Собственно, описание [метки на MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/10k-tools). Надо будет поправить переводы на русский.

Comment: Вот. Поставить на общую комнату модераторами - модераторов, а остальных выпнуть — норм. Если я правильно понял ответ.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ну... Если мы хотим считать нашу самую густонаселённую комнату общей. Вопрос отвлечённый, хотя кандидат на применимость всего один. Пока что.

Comment: @D-side я за.. ..не съехавшего крышей)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский эм, я про комнаты. :) Комнаты как кандидаты на применение этого правила.

Comment: @D-side ааа) считай, что я выразил позицию обо всё сразу)

Answer (score 3):

На мой взгляд любой участник сообщества может быть *владельцем* (следует читать как модератор конкретного чата) в случае выполнения им некоторых ограничений:

- Не принимать решение **единолично** о переносе/удалении сообщений (исключения вида мат и явный офтоп);
- **Не снимать** звезды с сообщений, поставленных участниками чата.

Решение о добавлении условной роли *модератор чата*, как мне кажется, необходимо принимать сообща.

Comment: Где та тонкая грань между явным и неявным офтопом? Особенно учитывая текущие метки чата.

Comment: @alexolut, очевидно это и должен определять владелец комнаты :-D

Comment: "Снимать звезды с сообщений, поставленных участниками чата." - это еще зачем вообще?

Comment: @Bald да. Не совсем понимаю, в каком контексте вы упоминаете эту фичу в ответе - дать права каждому снимать звезды? И не понимаю зачем админам/модераторам это в принципе.

Comment: @Bald спасибо за разъяснение. Тогда возможно вы забыли добавить "НЕ снимать звезды .." ?

Comment: Так ... про звёзды я что-то либо неправильно прочитал, либо не так понял. Вы о разрешении снимать звёзды или о запрете?

Comment: почему "не переносить", но "снимать" (а не "не снимать")?

Comment: @Bald перечитайте еще раз плиз, я поменял пункты местами для наглядности. Владельцем может быть любой участник, но на него накладываются следующие ограничения: снимать звезды с сообщений поставленных другими участниками, не переносить/удалять сообщения по своему желанию.

Answer (score 1):

*Владельцем* общего чата может быть только модератор, но на мой взгляд ограничения в этом случае должны накладываться те же, что и предъявляемые к рядовому участнику.

Answer (score -4):

Ну, у нас вполне просвещённое первое лицо: если бы его действия не устраивали бы большую часть чата, то негатив бы уже давно выплеснулся в обсуждение на мету.

Мне не совсем понятен посыл топикстартера. Будем говорить прямо. Под "назрел вопрос" видимо подразумевается, что есть какие-то конкретные претензии по конкретным действиям.

В такой ситуации можно пойти самым простым путём. Можно обрисовать конкретную проблему на мете и подождать, пока в голосовании выскажется активная часть сообщества. Так будет видно, есть ли значимая проблема или проблемы нет, а есть некоторое недовольное меньшинство мнение которого погоды не делает.

С этой точки зрения поднятый вопрос неконкретен и неконструктивен: надо более чётко артикулировать проблему, а не декларировать общими словами наличие проблем.

Но в вопросе есть много положительных и любопытных моментов, на которые я бы хотел бы обратить ваше внимание.

На stackoverflow есть много чатиков и они вполне хорошо защищены общими правилами stackoverflow. В некоторых ([политота](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47216/ru-so)) установлены [отдельные правила](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34771277#34771277).

[image: вот наши текущие правила]

А какие должны быть правила в месте, которое мы хотим видеть как наше общее место? Какие правила должны быть установлены сверх общих правил so для того, чтобы наше общение было эффективным и комфортным?

Nicolas на мой взгляд [правильно ставит проблему](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/37724188#37724188):

> Вопрос – не про конкретного участника, а про то, что может делать
>   владелец комнаты, а чего делать не следует

Небольшая цитата:

> Мы, народ Соединенных Штатов, в намерении образовать более совершенный
>   союз, установить правосудие, упрочить внутреннее спокойствие,
>   обеспечить внешнюю безопасность, споспешествовать общему
>   благосостоянию, обеспечить нам самим и нашему потомству блага свободы,
>   предписываем и установляем эту конституцию.

Вполне нормально было бы активным меньшинством при молчаливом нейтралитете большинства обсудить то, каким мы хотим видеть общий чат и какие в ним должны быть правила. При этом вопрос "кто может быть первым лицом чата" автоматически снимается: это должен быть человек, который следит за соблюдением общих правил, руководствуясь их духом и буквой. (И представьте себе: это может оказаться вполне себе текущее лицо)

Подведу итоги.

Для меня важно понять, насколько велик негатив по текущим действиям управляющего чата. Есть проблемы, велики они? Если есть -- нужно писать на мету и обсуждать. Это первое.

И второе, в случае если проблемы есть. По какому пути идти: путём обсуждения конкретных кейсов (инцидентное реагирование: если всё хорошо, то и нечего трындеть за глобальные правила) или путём выработки общих правил чата (от общего к частному).

Updated. Из обсуждения в чате у меня сложилось мнение, что нужно высказаться по вопросу удаления сообщений в чате (переносе в другие чаты) и посмотреть, есть ли сложившийся консенсус в обществе. Если кому есть что сказать -- прошу перейти в [эту тему](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5288/213987).

Comment: если честно я совсем ничего не понял из вашего ответа. моя тема как раз таки и есть попытка обговорить *правила игры*