# Главный чат. Удаление и перенос сообщений

Tags: обсуждение, чат

Вопрос по недавним обсуждениям в чате. Есть чат, предназначенный для общих дискуссий.

Нужно ли из него переносить сообщения в другие чаты, нужно ли удалять сообщения? Устраивает ли текущая ситуация, всё ли в ней хорошо или есть проблемы? Если есть проблемы -- можете ли вы предложить варианты лучше, чем есть сейчас?

Хочется понять, какие мнения по этому вопросу сложились в сообществе, поэтому готовых голосовалок не будет -- прошу именно высказываться ответами.

Comment: По сносу/запиныванию звёздных сообщений тоже вопрос будет?

Comment: @alexolut Знаете, от меня пожалуй не будет. Я не вижу там вопроса , так как всё достаточно однозначно на мой взгляд. Если кому-то интересно поднять эту тему -- почитаю, возможно даже и присоединюсь к обсуждению.

Comment: Любопытно, что никто не хочет пока оставить ответы в стиле "надо удалять и переносить", возможно ли, что это действительно воспринимается большинством негативно?

Comment: Молчаливое большинство! Боятся гнева Грюндия! :)

Answer (score 8):

В общем и целом удалять надо только спам/флуд и явные оскорбления в адрес участников.

Однако иногда бывают ситуации с поглощением чата небольшой группой участников (а то и вовсе двумя людьми). В таком случае было бы логичным перенести эту частную дискуссию в отдельный тематический чат.

Такое поведение как сейчас, когда совершенно невинные сообщения переносятся во Флудильню или Урну, мне не кажется правильным. Некоторые сообщения также ошибочно переносятся в Политоту.

Comment: Мне нравится этот ответ и я не вижу смысла писать новый, но хочется немного дополнить. Я думаю, любой участник чата, не обязательно модератор чата может предложить этой группе перейти в более подходящую комнату (и обычно у нас народ в чате достаточно адекватный, чтобы понять просьбу) чтобы продолжить общение там. Что делать с теми, кто не сразу понимает просьбы и достаёт собравшихся своим общением? Механизм "пожаловаться на сообщение" не будет слишком крут для этого? Альтернативу вижу в варианте голосовать звёздами за принудительный перенос сообщений в подходящий чат.

Comment: Тех, кто достаёт своим общением рано или поздно ждёт [416](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3776/176217). Если кто-то что-то не понял, не надо выяснять отношения и переходить на личности. Пусть <s>страдают</s> разбираются с этим модераторы. Но проблема в том, что флаг по текущей логике работы чата может прилететь совсем не русскоязычному модератору SE.

Comment: @alexolut, механизм жалоб не то что не крут, он вообще не подходит для этого, ибо созывает всех модераторов со всего SE. А нерусскоговорящий вряд ли будет разбираться в наших тонкостях — удалит флагнутое сообщение и всё.

Answer (score 4):

Ничего не удалять.

Переносить, думаю, тоже не нужно. Ну кроме тем, по наличию которых были возражения у участников чата (когда выделили [Политота на ru.SO](//chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47216/ru-so) - других примеров не знаю).

Если ещё возникнут подобные ситуации, то действовать по той же схеме.

Answer (score -2):

Не вижу особых проблем в переносе/удалении каких либо сообщений в чате