# Голосование о назначении владельца общего чата

Tags: обсуждение, статус-отклонено, чат

По результатам обсуждения в чате и на Мете, спешу предложить сообществу определиться, нужен ли общему чату владелец из числа участников не модераторов, и если да, то кто им станет.

#### Нужен ли владелец общего чата?

Пожалуйста, проголосуйте ***за (против) этот вопрос***, если вы считаете, что нам следует (не следует) выбирать владельца общего чата, для его модерирования.

#### Выдвижение кандидатуры

Основная задача (и ответственность!) владельца общего чата сводится к своевременному переносу нетематических для данного чата сообщений в другие специализированные чаты.

Как мне кажется, владелец общего чата – это тот человек, который активно его читает, при этом требования активно писать – нет.

Если вы считаете, что вы бы были хорошим владельцем общего чата, пожалуйста, опубликуйте ответ на этот вопрос. В вашем ответе укажите:

1. Краткую информацию о себе (с профессиональной точки зрения).
2. Какой ваш интерес к чату.
3. Почему вы хотите стать владельцем общего чата.

#### Голосование за участников

Если вам понравился кто–либо из кандидатов, пожалуйста, поддержите его своим голосом – проголосуйте за него!

#### Как принимается решение?

Решение принимается на основе голосования участников сообщества. Голосование будет считаться состоявшимся если:

- Данный вопрос будет иметь положительный рейтинг и минимальное количество голосов за.
- В ответах к этому вопросу будут кандидаты с положительным рейтингом и минимальным количеством голосов за.
- Минимальное количество голосов за – 3.

Голосование продлится до 30 июня 2017 года 23:59 по Москве.

С нетерпением ждем ваших откликов и голосов!

**Обновление**

У нас нет какого–то ограничения на количество владельцев чата с одной стороны. С другой стороны, как мне кажется, оптимальное количество активных модераторов чата – 2.

---

*Подводя итоги.*

На момент закрытия голосования в 23:59 30 июня, как видно из логов, вопрос о назначении имел 21 голос за и 20 против. Как результат, сообщество приняло решени о назначении владельцев общего чата.

Модераторами на основе голосов сообщества становятся:

- [@alexolut](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5501/6), с результатом +23/-14
- [@Abyx](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5550/6), с результатом +4/-2.

Поздравляю сообщество с отличным выбором! Огромное спасибо всем кандидатам за выдвижение своих кандидатур! Уверен, с новыми модераторами общей комнаты в основном чате станет больше диалогов о программировании и меньше отвлеченных тем.

**Обновление**

В следствии огромного количества тревог в чате, результаты голосования отменены (причина: связано оно с выбранными владельцами или нет, но чат стал не удовлетворять требованиям предъявляемым к содержимому, размещаемому на платформе Stack Exchange). Будущее данной инициативы подлежит дальнейшему обсуждению сообществом.

Comment: Сколько может быть владельцев?

Comment: @Aid Мы не накладываем каких–либо ограничений на количество.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky наверное, это стоит отразить в теле сообщения. Так как у меня тоже возник такой вопрос.

Comment: Возможно, есть смысл кандидатам обозначить свой часовой пояс, чтобы понимать ориентировочное время присутствия в чате.

Comment: @AK и знать, когда можно спаммить безнаказанно :)

Comment: @alexolut, а по приходу модератора, кто-то ему накапает на спамеров и баня :)

Comment: @Aid тогда нужно еще одно голосование на помощника (стукача) модератора :)

Comment: @alexolut, "Старший помощник Бом, ну-ка доложите мне что было и компромат на Grundy достаньте!".

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky А если хочу чтобы вы и/или избранные модераторы управляли общим чатом то, надо голосовать против? И будут ли вы и/или ромбовые модераторы модерировать чат по возможности в случае выбора или невыбора кого-то из немодераторов?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov если у вопроса будет неположительный рейтинг, то голосование будет считаться несостоявшимся и никто новый назначен не будет. Аналогично, если положительного рейтинга не будет ни у кого из кандидатов. Пока что у alexolut есть шансы.

Comment: @D-side И что? Николас и ромбовые модераторы будут следить за чистотой общего чата или нет?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov они и так следят, просто редко вмешиваются.

Comment: @D-side Проблема именно в этом – из коллектива модераторов нет человека, который часто сидит в чате, что может привести к негативным последствиям.

Answer (score 9):

[@alexolut](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/176217/alexolut) - [локализатор Всея ruSO](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4066/176217).

В чате [люблю дёргать Николаса](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81&user=178278&room=22462), что помогает некоторым [окунуться в своё прекрасное детство](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=35710186#35710186). Неоднократно необоснованно попадал под гнёт переноса Grundy. Тем не менее готов поддержать его кандидатуру, если он обещает исправиться :) Моя основная позиция по переносу сообщений из чата озвучена в [соответствующем ответе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5290/176217). Готов попробовать себя в роли не столько владельца, сколько совладельца чата. В новые обязанности лучше вникать постепенно, а стало быть разделять общую ответственность. Тем более, что чат вполне себе общий. Часовой пояс - UTC+3.

Comment: "Люблю дёргать Николаса" xD

Answer (score 4):

[@Abyx](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/177684/abyx). Let's make the chat great again!

Не буду переносить сообщения. Но когда надо - буду.

Голосуй, или проиграешь!

Comment: Ну а что, до конца голосования 6 часов, вполне себе вовремя)

Comment: Поддерживаю, неожиданное выдвижение.

Comment: StackOverflow на русском - это иллюстрация российского государства в миниатюре( всю власть захватили выходцы из Питера ))

Answer (score -4):

[**@Grundy**](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/175841/grundy) - [*Единственный профессионал™*](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=28650406#28650406)

[Участник, выбранный на пост владельца самой системой!](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=27939940#27939940)

Кто еще сможет уследить за чистотой и порядком в чате?!

Избавим общий чат от политоты и флуда!

---

Вернем истинному владельцу его полномочия!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: особенно понравилась реакция системы на вопрос "чойта такое" - http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/27941059#27941059

Comment: А разве не из-за вас началась вся эта катавасия с переназначением владельцев чата? И после этого вы хотите избраться обратно?

Comment: И да, вас уже [как минимум второй раз](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=29298996#29298996) попросили с поста (со)владельца.

Comment: @Arhad, на самом деле, это скорее из-за завистников :-) Ну и [_меня попросили_](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=38265858#38265858)

Comment: @Arhad, добрейшей души модер с непомерными амбициями - разве не такого мы ждём? :)