# Тематические дни в чате

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

Приветствую.

<s>Возникла идея делать тематические дни в [главной чат-комнате ruSO](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--).

Я бы рад в другой комнате, но у нас народ только в главной и находится. Вместе веселее?</s>
По итогам словесных баталий, было принято решение что главная комната категорически не подходит, надо ещё выбрать где устраивать игрища.
Быть может [тут](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60075/)?
Здесь и далее "день" - это 24 часа, начинающиеся с 00:02:52:132 AM UTC.

Например:

- Разговор только на английском русскими буквами (а ю сириосли? Оф коз, дуд!).
- Общение только словами N символов длиной (исключая предлоги, местоимения и ники).
- Общение словами начинающиеся на одну тематическую букву (- Ты телепат? Так точно, товарищ таракан!).
- Предлагайте своё.

RFC следующее (так же в открыта для предложений):

1. В чате происходит голосование начать ли день и на какую тему. Голоса определяются звёздами.
2. Кто-то из владельцев/модераторов чата ставит метку [тематический-день](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8c) и в описании добавляет что именно сегодня происходит в чате.
3. Общающиеся следуют правилам.

Уай нот?

Comment: Время по UTC выбираем?

Comment: Идея неплохая, но поддержать могу только при одном условии. Главная чат-комната -- она по-определению общая. А что делать остальным, кому тематический день мешает? Поэтому идите с вашими тематическими кодгольфами в отдельный чат.

Comment: Да, 24 часа, начало в 0 ночи.

Comment: @AK, как показала практика - народ никак не хочет идти в другие комнаты, хотя они сделаны именно для их нужд (флудилка, например).

Comment: @Aid, я думаю надо активнее подталкивать народ в другие комнаты, флудилку, например :-)

Comment: @Grundy, пиарите, значит? Пробовали, знаем - народу лень.

Comment: @Aid, не в 0, а в 0:02

Comment: @Nofate, Мы - уважаемое сообщество, не можем себе такого позволить. Вот 00:02:52:132 - пожалуйста.

Comment: @AK Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий ответом!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, Ваше мнение можно узнать?

Comment: @AK по итогам [обсуждения](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5291/181100) комнату по ссылке считать общей в данный момент нельзя.

Comment: @Aid Идея крайне интересная! Поддерживаю, но не в основном чате. В основном чате, к примеру, можно оставить сообщение и попросить владельца закрепить ее в боковой панели.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, обновил предложение.

Comment: `00:02:52:132` — какой именно источник эталонного времени класса stratum 1 будет использоваться для объявления старта?

Comment: @Arhad, http://time-a.nist.gov

Comment: @D-side мой плюс тоже есть там, потому что де-юре действительно нельзя считать общей, пусть даже она де-факто такой почти и является. Это очень печально и я говорил о том, что это важное противоречие, которое очень важно устранить. Называйте это любым словом, но я -- за национализацию, раскулачивание, легализацию.

Answer (score 7):

Идея неплохая, но поддержать могу только при одном условии.

> Главная чат-комната -- она по-определению общая, хорошо бы не мешать другу. Уже возникал вопрос о правилах для общей комнаты, [см. тут](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5284/213987).

А что делать остальным, кому тематический день мешает?

Поэтому идите с вашими тематическими <s>кодгольфами</s> днями в отдельный чат.

Answer (score 2):

Что ж, проверим заинтересованность эмпирически ([чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60075/)):

#### 08/06/2017 с 00:02:52:132 AM UTC пройдёт "День буквы"

"День буквы" - в этот день все слова (исключая предлоги, местоимения и ники) должны начинаться на букву "В".

---

Что ж, ожидаемо, но игрища в других, пустых комнатах не взлетели.
Печально.
Всем спасибо за внимание.

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста в какой комнате решили проводить?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, да, надо было написать: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60075/

Comment: Весело у вас там!)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, посмотрите внимательней :)

Comment: Насчёт "ожидаемо, но игрища в других, пустых комнатах не взлетели": я почему-то уверен, что в основном чате могло бы оказаться ещё меньше сообщений, потому что бы никто не стал бы поддерживать и инициатива заглохла бы ещё быстрее. В общем-то можно попробовать разок в общем чате провести и сравнить результаты.

Comment: @AK, исходите радугой и оптимизмом :) Главный чат не поддержат, мы это уже видели.

Comment: @Aid один раз для благой цели тестирования -- почему бы и нет?

Answer (score -2):

Идею поддерживаю, было бы интересно.

> А что делать остальным, кому тематический день мешает?

Ну ужесли прям мешает, то игнорировать.

Впрочем, народ в чате один и тот же, так что не вижу в этом проблемы.